# fopen two processes

Tags: c

Is it ok to have two processes writing to same file multiple times in a certain span of time usign fopen(append mode), fprintf, fclose functionality.
they wait for data and repeat the open,write,close operation.

is there a chance of data not being written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two processes are accessing the same file, you should use a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684266(VS.85).aspx) to prevent both processes from writing to the file at the same time.

The link above is for Windows platforms.  For other platforms, you'll need the platform's appropriate construct, such as a pthreads mutex created with `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED`.

Answer (score 1):

The `fopen()` function opens the file with no sharing protections (`SH_DENYNO`), at least on Win32/VC++, so without some kind of locking protocol you'll potentially corrupt the file.

If your app is Win32 you can use the `CreateFile` API to specify sharing modes.  The `_fsopen()` function is somewhat more portable, but not as portable as `fopen()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not on Windows, the easiest way among cooperating processes is to use [flock](http://google.com/search?q=man+flock).  (Use [fdopen](http://google.com/search?q=man+fdopen) to get a FILE from a fd.)